# Remove duplicated values function

Tags: php

```
function remove_values($arr){
    $_a = array();
    while(list($key,$val) = each($arr)){
        $_a[$val] = 1;
    }
    return array_keys($_a);
}
```

i can't follow the above function well.i don't know what's the effect of  `$_a[$val] = 1;`  anyone can explain it to me thank you

Comment: hmmm.. Why do not you use array_unique function?

Comment: it just for learn. i see the function from the internet i want to  understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all this does is to insert the value into the key of an array. Since all keys are unique in an array, you will remove all duplicates.

`array_keys()` simply gives back that array in it's ordinary form.

Example:

```
$arr = array('red', 'green', 'red');

$arr = remove_values($arr);
```

gives

```
array( 'red' => 1,
       'green' => 1);
```

which results in

```
array('red', 'green');
```

since "red" can only be a keyvalue once.

Comment: i fell that   $_a[$val] = 1   line the 1 can replace with other value am i right? thank you

Comment: Yes, you can. It can be `$_a[$val] = FALSE`, `$_a[$val] = TRUE` or whatever. It doesn't matter since that is a [dummy value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of the function, Why not just use [`array_unique($array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

**Like this**

```
function remove_values($arr){
    return array_keys(array_unique($arr));
}
```

---

#### Update:

Ok, Since you are trying to learn. Here is the explanation for the function in the post

```
function remove_values($arr){
    $_a = array(); //Creates a temporary array to store matching
    while(list($key,$val) = each($arr)){ //till their is item is array, loop it 
        $_a[$val] = 1; //Store in the temporary array with array's values as index, thus eliminating the duplicates
           //^ Here storing with the value as index IS THE KEY
    }
    return array_keys($_a); //return only the keys, which in fact are the unique values
}
```

Comment: it just for learn. i see the function from the internet i want to  understand it.

Comment: Starx , i fell that $_a[$val] = 1  the 1 can replace with other value eg: 0 . am i right? thank you

Comment: @user1345545, Sure.. it does not matter what values it is, the main thing the index.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice function actually.

```
$_a[$val] = 1;
```

makes every element to be signed once, so returned once meaning that duplicates are removed. Than the array_keys($_a) function rebuilds and sorts the array. I liked it.

Comment: i  am sorry i am a new learner of php. i still don't know how the above function do remove the duplicate value of an array

Answer (score 0):

its assign the value 1 to value part. for ex:

```
<?php

function remove_values($arr){
    $_a = array();

    while(list($key,$val) = each($arr)){
        $_a[$val] = 1;

    }
    print_r($_a);
    return array_keys($_a);
}

$arr = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');
$sed = remove_values($arr);
print_r($sed);
?>
```

It return two array values:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => 1
    [banana] => 1
    [cranberry] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [2] => cranberry
)
```

Now tis easy for you to understand the effect of value '1'.